# Gradle error: Library has broken path

Tags: java, gradle

I have added the gradle depencies as below and ran the gradle build command but still getting the below error

Error in below code in package import statement

```
  import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
  import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
  import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
  import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
  import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;

    dependencies {
     compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.10.29'
    }

    Below error getting in File -> Project Structure ->Module
```

[image]

I tried adding gradle apply plugin idea but that does't help me as in below code

apply plugin: 'idea'

Comment: Solved this issue by adding the below line in build.gradle             repositories {
    maven { url " https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk" }
    mavenCentral()
}